# Google maps api javascript doesn't work in mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mozilla

I found a script on google maps api page where user can select location and send data to PHP -> MySQL. It works fine in chrome and IE, but when i try to save location in mozilla, all it does is refresh parent page. 
I'm pretty much clueless when it comes to javascript, so if anyone can find error, would appreciate it :)

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
    <head>
        <meta name=viewport content='initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
        <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var marker;
            var infowindow; 

            function initialize() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.137550, -42.187500);
                var options = { 
                    zoom: 1, 
                    center: latlng, 
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), options);
                var html = "<table><tr><td><input type='button' value='Save Location' onclick='saveData(), window.parent.location.reload();'/></td></tr></table>";
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: html
                });

                function addMarker(location) {
                    if (!marker) {
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: location,
                            map: map
                        });
                    }
                    else { marker.setPosition(location); }
                }

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                    addMarker(event.latLng);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                });
            }   

            function saveData() {
                var latlng = marker.getPosition();
                var url = 'insert_location.php?lat=' + latlng.lat() + '&lng=' + latlng.lng();
                downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
                    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length >= 1) {
                        infowindow.close();
                    }
                });
            }

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
                var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                new XMLHttpRequest;

                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState == 4) {
                        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                        callback(request.responseText, request.status);
                    }
                };

                request.open('GET', url, true);
                request.send(null);
            }

            function doNothing() {}


        </script>
    </head> 
    <body style='margin:0px; padding:0px;' onload='initialize()'>
        <div id='map-canvas' style='width: 100%; height: 800px'></div>
        <div id='message'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `window.parent.location.reload` doing in there?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript isn't off by default, but maybe yours is turned off.

**If you want to turn Javascript on, please do the following:**

Type about:support into your address bar, press Enter

Accept the warning

Search for javascript.enabled

Make sure the value is true. (Double click it if it is not)

And statements like this - "**I'm pretty much clueless when it comes to javascript**" aren't going to help you. Put some effort into it and research before you come here asking for the rest of us to solve your issue for you.